# Showing More Meta Options? [Tumblr]

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm making a Tumblr theme, that I want to have a few different options. The idea being that if an option is chosen, more options will appear below, relating to aforementioned selection. But the options disappear again when the option is deselected.

This is the code I've been playing around with:

```
<meta name="if:More Meta" content="0" />
{block:IfMoreMeta}
    <meta name="if:Shown One" content="1" />
    <meta name="if:Shown Two" content="1" />
    <meta name="if:Shown Three" content="1" />
{/block:IfMoreMeta}
```

The code here uses the Tumblr `block:if` to, in theory, make more options appear once the `if:More Meta` has been enabled. But, as you can tell from me posting this question, it doesn't work.

Comment: "more options appear once the if:MoreMeta has been enabled", you mean appear on the sidebar?

Comment: No, `{block:IfXXX}{/block:IfXXX}` can not be used to toggle meta options. Meta options are stored by Tumblr when a theme is first loaded. These are only changed when you load a different theme.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I know: Unless they are "[Global Appearance](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#global_appearance)" options, the Boolean options like `{block:IfDoSomething}` specified inside the theme works at the blog's web page, example; "staffs.tumblr.com", and in the preview part of the theme customization page. The part where you see all the theme options in customization page shows any Tumblr specific meta tags ("[Theme Options](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options)") you have inside your theme HTML.

For the web page;

Tumblr only sends the `block` of code inside `{block:IfDoSomething}` and `{/block:IfDoSomething}` in response if the set condition is true.

Tumblr will not send the codes inside `{block:IfDoSomething}` and `{/block:IfDoSomething}` in response, if you have *disabled* the option, for example.

For the customization section;

When some specific meta tags are used in the theme's HTML (those that are set by Tumblr for "Theme Options"; meta-if, meta-color, meta-font tags etc.), Tumblr shows them all as options (example; toggles, buttons, text fields etc.) in the theme customization section. You can not set additional conditions  to show or hide them.

What you can control (for now) is; have or not have the meta tags, to have or not have the options in the theme customization page. And the type of options, by using different type of meta tags.

So your code (as in the question) would not work. It would be really cool if something like that worked though. I will update if I find some way to do what you want, or something similar.

**Update:**

What you are asking is possible with JavaScript. You can use the "inspect element" in your browser to get ids (or id patterns) of the options and make an algorithm for when to show or hide them (based on how you want it to be). The ids (ids, classes, etc.) options get are based on the title of the option in the meta tag (from what I found).

There are major drawbacks to this approach; you have very little control, and changes to the customization section (by Tumblr) will most probably make your algorithms useless, worse do something horrible like hide wrong options or something else because of some errors.

If you can avoid it, I do not recommend it. I only mentioned about this approach because you have the "JavaScript" tag in your question. I assumed you want some answer about if you can do something for the kind of functionality you want, with JavaScript.